# Non constant geometric sequence problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, contest-math, geometric-series

A problem on the national maths competition which I can't solve no matter how hard I try. It's high school maths so it shouldn't be that difficult. So here is the question:

How many prime numbers can a non constant geometric sequence of positive real numbers contain?

Comment: If you don't know what a geometric sequence is, then this problem is going to be tough. I'd suggest you read up on geometric sequences first, do a few simpler exercises, then come back to this problem when you've had done practice.

Comment: Of course I know what a geometric sequence is, I just don't know what a non constant one is.. because english is not my first language. Does it basically mean that the different elements have different values?

Comment: It simply means the ratio of the sequence is different from $1$.

Comment: oh haha, that that problem is solved.. now just need to figure out how to solve the actual problem

Comment: Let us know your answer.

Comment: Write out a generic geometric sequence which of those terms are for sure not prime?

Comment: So I basically take all the multiples of prime numbers and the numbers that are left are prime numbers of the sequence.. But how can I calculate all of them, since real numbers go to infinity?

Comment: Did you try what I wrote? Anyway another hint, if you have the $n$th term in a sequence then what is the $n+1$th term? How do they relate? What is a prime number?

Comment: you are all thinking integer ratio's that need not apply.